# How can I add a listener on the ok button of JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, joptionpane

How can I add a listener on the click of "OK" button of `JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE`.

My JOptionPane is:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your password is: " + password, "Your Password", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Why do you need listener? Is not the returned value enough?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that it return an integer value, Now I can use the returned value....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method returns void when the user closes or clicks ok. But you can use the method [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) with a single `DEFAULT_OPTION` for the OK button. The `showOptionDialog` will return 0 if OK was clicked and -1 if the user closed the dialog.

```
int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello", "Test", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

System.out.println(res);
```

You don't need a listener because the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) says:

> Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete.

Answer (score 3):

When the button on `JOptionPane` is clicked, it returns the index value of button.
By checking the value, you can get to know that `Ok` button is clicked or not.